# How to dynamically append to a lightning map marker list

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-map

I am building a LWC which shows markers on a map after a user searches for an item. I have tried to create the markers dynamically but I can't seem to get the proper way of doing it.

I have an array that contains the list which is used to search created like this..

```
//partial code
 pEngage.state = element.State__c;
 pEngage.city = element.City__c;
 pEngage.zip = element.Zip_code__c;
 pEngage.street = element.Street__c;
 
 prepEng.push(pEngage);
 this.searchList =  prepEng;
```

To search the item..

```
if(this.num > 0){
  for(var i = 0; i< this.searchResult.length; i++){
    let searchId = this.searchResult[i];
    var index = this.searchIds.findIndex(engId => engId === searchId);                 
    this.finalDisplay = [...this.finalDisplay, this.searchList[index]];
    this.mapArray = [...this.mapArray, this.searchList[index]];
  }
}
```

So I am now using **mapArray** to create the mapMarkers which according to the documentation should be created like this..

```
mapMarkers = [{
    location: {
        Street: '1 Market St',
        City: 'San Francisco',
        Country: 'USA'
    },
    title: 'The Landmark Building',
    description: 'Historic <b>11-story</b> building completed in <i>1916</i>'
}];
```

My code which is not working..

```
viewMaps(){
  this.mapVisible =  true;
  
  for(var i = 0; i<this.mapArray.length; i++){
    let markers = [{
      location: {
        Street:this.mapArray[i].street,
        City: this.mapArray[i].city, 
        PostalCode: this.mapArray[i].zip,
        State: this.mapArray[i].state
      },
      description: '<b>Name of Engagement Initiative/Project/Program: </b>' + this.mapArray[i].name
    }];
  
    this.map.splice(i, 0, markers);
  }
  this.mapMarkers = this.map;
  console.log('Map markersy '+ JSON.stringify(this.mapMarkers));
}
```

The template is checking whether mapMarkers is true.

```
 <template if:true={mapMarkers}>                                     
                <lightning-map   
                    map-markers={mapMarkers}
                    markers-title="Engagement Distribution"
                    zoom-level={zoomLevel}
                    list-view={listView}>
                    </lightning-map>     
         </template>
```

I have tried using the spread operator as well as object.assign but they both return a list of lists of objects which cause the error
`(Cannot read property 'Latitude' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {markup://lightning:map})`

Any ideas? Thanks.

The returned object is shown in this image[image]

Comment: please include the code/json from the logs instead of a screenshot

Comment: additionally, this error would normally produce itself if you were trying to access the property, however, you don't seem to have included this in your code snippets

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you using an array of markers as a reference and building the results from that? So every time there is a search, you want to create a subset for the full list of markers for display?

Comment: Casper, I have added the template code that is trying to access the markers generated after the search.

Comment: @glls I am not sure I know what you mean by code from the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't really see what you are trying to do. For example - searching on an Id using an exact match - that's not really a search is it?

Because I don't know what you are trying to do, I can't point to the exact problem.

However, I can offer some help in general - which may potentially fix your issue(s)

To search the item, you should be using some sort of `Array.prototype` method, like
`Array.forEach` or `Array.some`. Something like this:

```
searchResult.forEach( searchId => {
  let index = this.searchIds.findIndex(engId => engId === searchId);                 
  this.mapArray = [...this.mapArray, this.searchList[index]];
});
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are destructuring the `mapArray` every time. This could get expensive.

Are you trying to keep old results in the array? Also, you could potentially end up with duplicates there - at no point to do you clear that array.

You could just push to an `intermediateResults` array and write that to the `mapArray` ouside of the loop.

For the next loop, you should be doing something similar - and you can use the built in `Array.prototype.map` function to process all the items. I don't see why you need `splice` here.

Also, you were adding in an `Array` containing a single `Object` to the `mapMarker` array, which would have resulted in an `Array[Array[{},{}]]` structure - which I don't think will work for you.

Do something like this:

```
viewMaps(){
  this.mapVisible =  true;
  this.mapMarkers = this.mapArray.map( mapItem => {
    return {
      location: {
        Street:mapItem.street,
        City: mapItem.city, 
        PostalCode: mapItem.zip,
        State: mapItem.state
      },
      description: '<b>Name of Engagement Initiative/Project/Program: </b>' + mapItem.name
    };
  });
}
```

Also, your template code is looking for the wrong variable:

```
<template if:true={mapMarkers}>
```

I think you meant:

```
<template if:true={mapVisible}>
```

Finally, none of this will really fix the issue unless you have a clear vision of what you are trying to do.

It might be a good idea to sketch out the various data flows and variables so you know what they are going to be doing.

Good luck - you are doing well!

Comment: Thank you so much Casper! You have saved the day! Its working! The arrow function maintained the data structure which is what I needed. I already had the search part working so the code I had shared here was after I  got the results which I needed to plot.

Comment: I am using the mapMakers to control the loading of the map template since I only want it to show after the data is ready.

Comment: That's great! I wasn't sure it was going to be useful - glad to hear it was! Nice one :)

Comment: Oh also I forgot to say - you should use the forEach and map functions because they are WAY faster when LockerService is activated (which it is in most circumstances)

Comment: thanks for the tip Casper. much appreciated. I am actually going to take your advice and modify my search which is using for loops.

Comment: The search is posted here. I could use your help again. :-) https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343290/improve-performance-of-a-complex-search